# If property provided, require another property

Tags: typescript

So I wish to create an interface, where I would have two optional properties, but if you provide either one, you have to provide another one as well e.g.

```
interface Link {
  url: string;
}

interface LinkWithImage extends Link {
  imageUrl: string;
  alt: string;
}

type EitherOne = Link | LinkWithImage
```

So what I'd like, is that when using type `EitherOne`, I'd have just one property or all three, but this makes it that as soon as I provide an `url` the type is always matching and properties of `LinkWithImage` become all optional.
I'd like that if you wish to pass an image, you are always required to pass alternative text as well

I know I could create separate functions to handle this situation but I'd like to know if this is somehow possible

Comment: You have a compilation error, what does `LinkWithImage` extend? `Link` ?

Comment: Yes sorry, I didn't notice that typo

Comment: It's weird, for some reason union types are not subject to the no unknown properties rule I got the desired effect using function overloads : `function x(p: Link)  function x(p: LinkWithImage)  function x(p: EitherOne) {  }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) along with union types. You would have to lose the interface inheritance though (or use `Pick<T>` to pick only properties present in `LinkWithImage` when using `Never<LinkWithImage>`)

```
interface Link  {
    url: string;
}

interface LinkWithImage {
    imageUrl: string;
    alt: string;
}

// Mapped type
type Never<T> = {
    [P in keyof T]?: never
}

type EitherOne = Link & Never<LinkWithImage> | LinkWithImage;

// No error
let x: EitherOne = {
    url: "a"
}

// Error
let y: EitherOne = {
    url: "a",
    imageUrl: "b"
}

// No error:
let z: EitherOne = {
    url: "a",
    imageUrl: "b",
    alt: "c"
}
```

Comment: Okay, this actually has some issues, if you try to do `z.url`, it throws error as url isn't within `LinkWithImage`, easy fix is to do `type EitherOne = Link & Never<LinkWithImage> | LinkWithImage & Link;`